# Haskell Chart.Simple glib.0.13.0.1 to GTK+2 link error

Tags: haskell, gtk2

This use if Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple

<<

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple
main = plotPDF "foo.pdf" [0,0.1..10::Double] sin
```

> >

produces this link error
<<

```
Linking chart4.exe ...
C:\Documents and Settings\myname\Application Data\cabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\glib-    0.13.0.1/libHSglib-0.13.0.1.a(hsgclosure.o):hsgclosure.c:(.text+
0x1a1): undefined reference to `g_value_set_schar'
>>
```

But as use of Graphics.Rendering.Chart works  fine

```
   https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki/example-1  
       (main = renderableToFile def chart "example1_big.png")
```

GTK is the bundled "gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32"

Answer (score 0):

This function (***g_value_set_schar***) is from the **gtk3**, so you will need to install it. Download and unpack the all-in-one bundle, add /bin to your %PATH% and install bindings.

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
cabal install gtk3
```